# How to Copy Excel Named Range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

I have a Named Range = $A$1:$S$34. I can't copy it in same sheet in another cell outside the named range. Would you please help?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Dear but you want to use the values of your NamedRange as a popup menu on the another cell?

Comment: I just want to paste the Named Range in another Cell having the same format and spacing. But "=Name" doesn't work.

Comment: Please add in your answer yuor Named Range definition. Which name you have assigned? and so on

Comment: I have a named range of "Challan_Form" which is a specific format for payment to Govt. treasury. Now I want to copy the Challan_Form on another page on the same sheet. "=Challan_Form" and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER produces "0" in output if I select same number of cell of named range and produces "#VALUE" error if I select one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of copy/paste a `Named Range`:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Range("$A$1:$S$34").Name = "HomeHomeOnTheRange"
    Range("HomeHomeOnTheRange").Copy Range("Z100")
End Sub
```

*(you can adapt this code to your `Name` and your destination cell)*

**EDIT#1:**

Here is an example of allowing the User to specify the destination at run-time:

```
Sub KopyKat2()
    Dim s As String

    s = Application.InputBox(prompt:="please enter destination address like" & vbCrLf & "S100:", Type:=2)

    Range("$A$1:$S$34").Name = "HomeHomeOnTheRange"
    Range("HomeHomeOnTheRange").Copy Range(s)
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't mean to pick nits but the four *$* in `$A$1:$S$34` are kinda unnecessary. Probably just left over from a Copy & Paste out of the question's particulars.

Comment: @Jeeped  **You are correct!**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Thanks for the code. Can you make the Range destination (i.e. "Z100" in your code variable, I mean, just like a relative reference?

Comment: @ShibbirAhamed  Would you like the User to specify the destination or have a variable in the ode itself ??

Comment: Yes. Thank You.

Comment: @ShibbirAhamed  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: `Sub CopyRange()
Range("Challan_Form").Copy Range("'Challan'!A1").Offset(34, 0)
End Sub`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Can I make the "34" in the above code linked with the input sheet rows just like - in the below function? "=OFFSET('Input Sheet'!$B$5, (ROW('Input Sheet'!A6) - 6)/34+1, 0)"

Comment: @ShibbirAhamed  .....................I do not know.